# Records can not be updated with below code

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite

Issues:

I can not update inserted records with the below code in my project. if update button will be clicked then record should be upated and should be displayed in Viewcontroller

code:

```
import UIKit

class UpdateScreen: UIViewController
{

    var strEmail:String!
    var dictRecord:NSDictionary!
    var databasepath:String!

    @IBOutlet weak var txtfld_Update_Name: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var txtfld_Update_Phone: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var txtfld_Update_Email: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var txtfld_Update_Comment: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        print(dictRecord!)

        txtfld_Update_Name.text! = (dictRecord["Name"]! as? String)!
        txtfld_Update_Phone.text! = (dictRecord["Phone"]! as? String)!
        txtfld_Update_Email.text! = (dictRecord["Email"]! as? String)!
        txtfld_Update_Comment.text! = (dictRecord["Comment"]! as? String)!

    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



    @IBAction func btnUpdateClicked(sender: AnyObject)
    {
        let filemgr = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
        let dirpaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentationDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
        let docDir = dirpaths[0] as String
        databasepath = docDir.stringByAppendingString("StudentDataManipulation.sqlite");

        if filemgr.fileExistsAtPath(databasepath as String)
        {
            let contactDB = FMDatabase(path: databasepath as String)

            if contactDB.open()
            {
                let sql_stmt = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS StudentData (Name TEXT, Phone TEXT, Email TEXT PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL, Comment TEXT)"

                if !contactDB.executeStatements(sql_stmt)
                {
                    print("Error: \(contactDB.lastErrorMessage())")
                }


                let updateSql:String = "UPDATE StudentData SET Name='\(txtfld_Update_Name.text!)', Phone='\(txtfld_Update_Phone.text!)', Comment='\(txtfld_Update_Comment.text!)'"

                print("updateSql before = \(updateSql)");

                let result = contactDB.executeUpdate(updateSql, withArgumentsInArray: nil)

                print("updateSql after = \(updateSql)");

                if !result
                {
                    print("Error: \(contactDB.lastErrorMessage())")
                }
                else
                {
                    print("Record Successfully Updated")
                    self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
                }
            }
            else
            {
                print("Error: \(contactDB.lastErrorMessage())")
            }
            contactDB.close()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your sql is wrong.
update tablename set field1=value1 and field2=value2 where id=xx

Comment: This works fine better than before, Record can be seen updated in console but in table it is not updated.

Comment: Are you using any sqlite manager like Datum? If yes, then sometimes they don't reload table automatically. You have to explicitly click on the reload button. Try that.